# react router v6 doesn't work if a question mark is attached to url

Tags: reactjs, react-router

So the situation i'm in , i have a link that's sent through our backend to the user which he tries to access to reset his password , that link's path is : https://randomwebsite.com/reset-password/?uidb64=value&token=value
my route component and 404 route component look like this:

```
    <Route
      path="/reset-password/?:uidb64:token"
      element={<ResetPasswordCodeConfirmation />}
    />

    <Route path="*" element={<Error404Page />} />
```

if i try to visit the link above ( https://randomwebsite.com/reset-password/?uidb64=value&token=value) i get to the 404 page , if i remove the question mark from both my route and link , it works out fine and the link goes to the reset password component but i need to tell react router that it needs to accept a question as this is the link that's getting to the user , any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is two different things here:

- Query params (Which your backend has for this end points) and it means adding values after the `?` character with `&` if you have multiple values
- Route params (Which you attempted to add in your route component using the character `:`) and it means actually a totally different route with `/` separating it, for ex: `<Route path="/reset-password/:token" />` means all  `https://randomwebsite.com/reset-password/AnyThingHereThatYouCanAccessLaterAsToken`

So, your link should remain the same, and your Route component should look like this:

```
    <Route
      path="/reset-password"
      element={<ResetPasswordCodeConfirmation />}
    />
```

I think this [link](https://learnwithparam.com/blog/how-to-handle-query-params-in-react-router/) has a good example of the same situation.

Comment: ohhh , that makes a lot of sense wow , It works perfectly now , thanks a bunch yasser :)

Comment: Sure anytime!, it would help if you can mark it as the correct answer for other people searching for it as well ;)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to add the question mark to the route path. React Router automatically parses the query parameters, and then you can use and validate the query params, like so:

```js
import { useSearchParams } from 'react-router-dom'
...
const [queryParams, setQueryParams] = useSearchParams()
if (!queryParams.uidb64 && !queryParams.token) {
    return <h1>Error</h1>
}
...
```

Or something like that. That's just an example.